# MULTIBLE ORACLE DATABASES IN A SINGLE WINDOWS SERVER

Tags: oracle10g

We have a windows server, where while installing Oracle, one database has been specified and created.  I want to create an application in ORACLE on the same server, but I want to create and use a different database for this application.  My mentor says that the server can hold only one ORACLE database and my request can not be implemented.  Is there a way out of this ?

Comment: Depends on the version/edition of Oracle and the server specification. Presumably your mentor has more specific knowledge about the environment than us. Why do you want to use a different database, won't a different schema on the existing DB do?

Comment: the oracle version is 10g.  i need to use a different database, because both the structure and the contents of the table are different (as it is for a totally different application), and i want to keep both our works discreete and non-interfering.